# Custom binary exporter, is this script possible to do?

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to create a binary exporter that does this in sequence:

1. Write fixed hex header, 8 bytes: "01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00"
2. Write custom hex ID1, 8 bytes
3. Write Custom hex ID2, 8 bytes
4. Write Custom hex ID3, 8 bytes
5. Write Custom hex ID4, 8 bytes
6. Write Custom hex ID5, 8 bytes
7. Write Custom hex ID6, 8 bytes
8. Texture number ID, 4 bytes uint Little endian
9. Write fixed hex, 8 bytes: "00 00 00 00 00 00 80 3F 00 00 80 3F 00 00 80 3F 00 00 80 3F 00 00 80 3F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00"
10. Write mesh 1 total lenght, 4 bytes uint little endian. *calculated by: ( 8 * polygon number) + 32 * total vertex )
11. Polygon 1 vertex data:

A) Write Custom hex ID7, 4 bytes uint Little endian

B) Write polygon 1 total vertex, 4 bytes uint Little endian

C) Write a total of 8 int floats, each one 4 bytes Little endian: X Y Z Xn Yn Zn U V

12. Continue by appending polygon 2 vertex data in the same format and so on

I am new to Blender and scripting, is this possible to do or it is too complex? :)

Comment: Blender uses python. There is no reason I can see to make  exporting its data to binary as described above or to fooble gimblewads  impossible. Too complex..? depends on your skill with python file IO.

Comment: Then I'll try doing it step by step thanks! Is there any noob-friendly tutorial on binary writing?